# How to translate a flat structure into a hierarchical on python

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm

I have .csv file, which have parent and children ID. How to translate a flat structure into a hierarchical?
**Example**
[.csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16EOE.png)

Comment: Can you share an example of what this csv actually looks like?  and of what your desired format is?  The description above is pretty confusing

Comment: I'm add how looks .csv file. 
I need to return the hierarchy from parent to child. For example, there is id 201, the hierarchy 123 -> 421 -> 201 should be displayed.